# Where to add option for auto spellcheck in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, spell-check

I can't seem to find the option to set "underline misspelled words in red" in Word 2007. Where is this located?

Do I have to install additional tools to have this option, or it's included with default installation of Word 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct,

1. Click on Top Left Corner Icon   [image]
2. Click on **Word Options**
3. From Left Navigation, click **Proofing**

   **Short Cut to open Word Options** - **`ALT + F + I`**

You will see spell Check related all options, modify accordingly.